# When is a newly created HDFS file considered available for read?

Tags: hdfs

Creating a HDFS file involves several things, metadata, allocating blocks, replicating blocks. My question is that, when is a file considered available for read? Does it need to wait until all blocks are fully replicated?

In my HDFS log, I noticed HDFS first allocated blocks for my mapreduce staging file:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1073743864_3041, replicas=10.206.36.220:9866, 10.206.37.92:9866, 10.206.36.186:9866, 10.206.36.246:9866, 10.206.38.104:9866, 10.206.37.119:9866, 10.206.37.255:9866, 10.206.37.129:9866, 10.206.38.97:9866, 10.206.38.5:9866 for /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/xxx/.staging/job_12345678_0567/job.split
```

but later the job failed to find the file:

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 80 on 8020, call Call#1 Retry#1 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.getBlockLocations from 10.206.38.106:46254: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/xxx/.staging/job_12345678_0567/job.split
```

finally I see

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1073744008_3185, replicas=10.206.37.253:9866, 10.206.36.167:9866 for /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/xxx/.staging/job_12345678_0567/job.split.1234567890._COPYING_
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/xxx/.staging/job_12345678_0567/job.split.1234567890._COPYING_ is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1702431035_1
```

I'm guessing the file has never been fully created.

Answer (score 1):

Data is available for read immediately after the flush operation.If a writer wants to ensure that data it has written does not get lost in the event of a system crash, it has to invoke flush. A successful return from the flush call guarantees that HDFS has persisted the data and relevant metadata. The writer can invoke flush as many times and as frequently as it needs. The writer can repeatedly write a few bytes to a file and then invoke flush. A reader that has the file already opened might not see that changes that this flush effected, but any re-opens of the file will allow the reader to access the newly written data. HDFS guarantees that once data is written to a file and flushed, it would either be available to new readers or an exception would be generated.  New readers will encounter an IO error while reading those portions of the file that are currently unavailable. This can occur if all the replicas of a block are unavailable. HDFS guarantees to generate an exception (i.e. no silent data loss) if a new reader tries to read data that was earlier flushed but is currently unavailable.